# Unable to open this project because the add-on software that was used to create it could not be found

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

When trying to deploy a project within PowerBuilder 10.5 I receive the message:

`Unable to open this project because the add-on software that was used to create it could not be found. Perhaps this project was built on another system?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to this was listed in an old newsgroup posting: [Unable to open Project because an add-on software not found](http://nntp-archive.sybase.com/nntp-archive/action/article/%3C0a075762-fdb6-4af5-9eb4-9114fedf9807@s21g2000prm.googlegroups.com%3E)

The issue was that I had two sets of PowerBuilder dll's in the path, but the location where the dll's for the IDE were located was listed as the second one in the path.  I modified the system path so the set of dll's that the IDE uses came first in the path and then the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

I am running PowerBuilder 12.5 on Windows 7 64-bit. The following steps fixed the issue for me:

1. Run regedit.exe
2. Do a search for pbvm125.dll.
3. Open the location given in the search result (i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\shared\PowerBuilder)
4. Open another Explorer window and navigate to C:\Windows
5. Do a search for pb*.dll
6. For every dll that starts with "pb" or "PB" in the search result, AND is already in the PowerBuilder folder, add a ".bak" extension. i.e. PBVM125.DLL.bak
7. Restart PowerBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this one, it works for me:

- Close the PowerBuilder
- In your Drive `C:\Windows\System32`
- Add new Folder "PB" and try to find "pbvm90.dll" in system32 folder and put it inside the PB folder.

I hope this will help you.. :)